# How does a program actually receives character input? From scan code to the final raw input bits

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, scancodes, low-level-io

So, my question is simple: How does a program receive the raw input bits after user "inputs" (from physical keyboard or any other way) a character key?

I mean I know how character encoding works *after* it's been received by the program as raw bits but I'm not clear about how that bit sequence appears in the first place.

I've been reading a little but this turned out to be a tough search for my Google-fu. It seems like the OS receives a scan code from the input device (usually keyboard), maps this to an encoding using character mappings and keyboard layouts, and then passes the resulting bit sequence to program. Am I right? If so, the only missing part for me is this:

1. How does keyboard layouts define what character a scan code
   corresponds to? Using Unicode code points? An OS specific internal
   table?
2. Secondly, does a program defines in which character encoding it's
   expecting its input (from OS) at compile time? Does it at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very good low-Level description on how to read from a keyboard as part of an assembler course. it covers the whole pipeline from the keystroke to the CPU. You can find the whole course [here](http://flint.cs.yale.edu/cs422/doc/art-of-asm/pdf/) and the chapter about keyboard input [here](http://flint.cs.yale.edu/cs422/doc/art-of-asm/pdf/CH20.PDF).